# Read or write message from/to file

Tags: ros, c++, serialization, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the easiest way to load/write a message from/to a file in C++?
I want something like this:

```
void loadMessage(const std::string& filename, std_msgs::Image& image_msg)
{
    // open file and put it's content in img_msg
}
void saveMessage(std_msgs::Image& image_msg, const std::string& filename)
{
    // put message content in file
}
```

The file has YAML format, for example created by

```
rostopic pub -1 /image std_msgs/Image > file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11289/read-or-write-message-from/to-file/) by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1924 on 2011-09-22

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-09-23**:
Do you mean that you want the output file to be in YAML format?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-09-23**:
Is there some reason not to use `rosbag`? That is the normal ROS technique; it can be done with standard commands.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-02-08**:
This is similar to http://answers.ros.org/question/10330/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-ros-message-to-a-string-or-xml/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way I see is to use rosbag. You can easily record messages from the command line by just executing

```
rosbag /topic1 /topic2
```

Rosbag also provides a C++ and a Python API for writing and reading streams of messages from your programs. Have a look at [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Code%20API) page for more information on the API.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

you can dump the message into a binary buffer. Attached you can see how I did it with a sensor_msgs::LaserScan.

```
void LaserLineFilterNode::callback (const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& _msg) {

    {
        // Write to File
        std::ofstream ofs("/tmp/filename.txt", std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);

        uint32_t serial_size = ros::serialization::serializationLength(*_msg);
        boost::shared_array<uint8_t> obuffer(new uint8_t[serial_size]);

        ros::serialization::OStream ostream(obuffer.get(), serial_size);
        ros::serialization::serialize(ostream, *_msg);
        ofs.write((char*) obuffer.get(), serial_size);
        ofs.close();
    }
    {
        // Read from File to msg_scan_
        //sensor_msgs::LaserScan msg_scan_ --> is a class variable
        std::ifstream ifs("/tmp/filename.txt", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
        ifs.seekg (0, std::ios::end);
        std::streampos end = ifs.tellg();
        ifs.seekg (0, std::ios::beg);
        std::streampos begin = ifs.tellg();

        uint32_t file_size = end-begin;
        boost::shared_array<uint8_t> ibuffer(new uint8_t[file_size]);
        ifs.read((char*) ibuffer.get(), file_size);
        ros::serialization::IStream istream(ibuffer.get(), file_size);
        ros::serialization::deserialize(istream, msg_scan_);
        ifs.close();
    }
    ....
```

More details on http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes

But I there is still an issue, I had to create a memory buffer fist, it would be nice to see how one can create a ros::serialization::OStream to stream directly into a file.

Hmm... I will post a separate question for that :-)

Greetings
Markus

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) with karma: 847 on 2014-02-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2014-05-20**:
so did you find how to serialize directly to a file?

**Comment by [Danfoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/32545/danfoa/) on 2019-05-24**:
The ros bag C++ API provides this functionality. see [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API#cpp_api)